# Finding which object has a reference to another object in iOS and ARC

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, instruments

I'm working in xcode and iOS, and I have an object that is not being deleted because some other object still has a reference to it, but I can't figure out who.  Using Instruments, I see that it has a ref count of 1, but as far as I can tell from looking at my code, it should be zero.

I've run Instruments and it doesn't see it as a leak.

If there a way in Instruments (or in the debugger) to find out who still has the reference?

Comment: Did you ever find the instrument to help you debugging? I am having the same problem now

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try and replace some strong references to weak, and see if it still holds?

Answer (score 0):

I guess we cannot help you very much in that case. Probably you have to follow the object through its intended lifecycle.

What you could try, is a category for NSObject, where you log every retain and release. You can also put breakpoints into these methods, so you see in the stacktrace (so from where it was retained/released).

Comment: I don't think under ARC the retain and release methods are called, not the traditional ones anyway.

Comment: `objc_release` and `objc_retain` are called under ARC.